# Kubuntu: how do I change an icon to .sage files which are plain text?

Tags: kubuntu, icons

I want Kubuntu 11.10 to show icons on several types of plain text files - depending on the extension. The problem is - KDE looks on the mime type - not on the extension. So if I do the usual way (see the image) all text files icons got changed - while I wanted to change icons of just `.sage` files.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...if I do the usual way...all text files icons got changed...

What is the usual way at there ?

At here: KDE system Settings > File Assosiations > Add file type text/sage.

[image]

Only the files with the extension sage got the sage icon.

[image]

Comment: My mistake was - that I was configuring it through `Edit File Type` in Krusader - while I should do it throught `KDE system Settings > File Assosiations > Add file type text/sage`